# Problemas al actualizar en MSSQL UPDATE DOBLE CODIGO

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

colegas un gusto, tengo un inconveniente a realizar un update combinando un merge.

Resulta que durante el proceso de actualización, en diversas ocasiones se recibe el mismo código, debido a que  en ocasiones los usuarios introducen datos de formas repetidas es decir pueden introducir dos veces el mismo código de producto en un solo proceso, esto debido a la forma en que vienen impresos los documentos con que los usuarios procesan la información, lo que causa que la consulta se detenga y no se pueda ejecutar.

Ejemplo:

| codigo | descripcion | precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | PRUEBA1 | 2.00 |
| A002 | PRUEBA1 | 4.00 |
| A001 | PRUEBA1 | 2.01 |

Como puedo hacer para que cuando pase la segunda vez por A001 la consulta no se detenga cuando consiga un código duplicado, me podrán orientar sobre que sentencia sql tendría que manejar para poderme documentar?.

Comment: No uso sql-server, pero supongo que es parecido a sqlite y a postgresql. Si haces que "codigo" no sea una primary key, entonces el código será ingresado repetido.

Comment: Es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: Y cual es el proceso que genera el error?

Comment: Por favor, muéstranos qué consulta genera el error y cómo está definida la tabla. Es posible que lo que te indica @DanteS. resuelva el problema, pero no lo sabemos porque no sabemos el error exacto

Comment: Dónde está tu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes hacer nada para que la operación de **[`merge`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** no falle si hay múltiples coincidencias pues, por definición, cada registro se puede actualizar como máximo una vez en cada sentencia. La documentación, de hecho, dice:

> La instrucción MERGE **no puede actualizar la misma fila más de una vez**, ni actualizar o eliminar la misma fila.

El énfasis es mío.

Lo que si puedes hacer es tomar acciones para que el registro aparezca una sola vez en los datos de entrada y, de esta manera, cumplir con actualizar el registro destino una sola vez. Si tus datos de entrada tienen una llave primaria consecutiva podrías, por ejemplo, quedarte con la última aparición de cada registro. Esto tiene lógica, pues la actualización realizada con esta útlima aparición *machacaría* todas las actualizaciones realizadas con apariciones anteriores.

Voy a suponer que tienes un campo llamado `secuencia` que es un campo auto-incremental en tu tabla de entrada, y que el campo `código` es la llave primaria o un índice único en la tabla destino, entonces, podríamos hacer algo como:

```
with
UltimaAparicion as (
select codigo, max(consecutivo) MaxConsecutivo
  from TablaOrigen
 group by Codigo
)
  merge 
   into TablaDestino as destino
  using (select TablaOrigen.Codigo, TablaOrigen.descripcion, TablaOrigen.precio
           from UltimaAparicion
                inner join TablaOrigen on TablaOrigen.consecutivo = UltimaAparicion.MaxConsecutivo
        ) as origen
     on destino.Codigo = origen.Codigo
  when matched 
   and (    Destino.Descripcion != origen.Descripcion
         or Destino.Precio != origen.Precio
       )
  then
update
   set   Descripcion = origen.Descripcion
       , Precio = origen.Precio
```

Si no tienes un campo llave que puedas utilizar, puedes definir otro criterio, como quedarte con el mayor precio, o con el menor.

Otra forma sería creando un campo incremental *al vuelo*, por ejemplo:

```
with
OrigenConConsecutivo as (
select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) consecutivo
  from TablaOrigen
)
,
UltimaAparicion as (
select codigo, max(consecutivo) MaxConsecutivo
  from OrigenConConsecutivo
 group by Codigo
)
  merge 
   into TablaDestino as destino
  using (select OrigenConConsecutivo.Codigo, OrigenConConsecutivo.descripcion, OrigenConConsecutivo.precio
           from UltimaAparicion
                inner join OrigenConConsecutivo on OrigenConConsecutivo.consecutivo = UltimaAparicion.MaxConsecutivo
        ) as origen
... etcetera
```

Comment: Yo creo que mas bien una solución en su caso, seria aplicar un insert con left join, y un update con inner join

Comment: @Eduardo, podrías escribir una respuesta dando esa solución ;)